# override variables from other classes

Tags: actionscript-3

Say i have a variable in a general `Global.as` file like this:

```
public static const test:String = "testString";
```

And in another file i want to override that variable. like following perhaps:

In `File1.as` :

```
override var test:String = "testStringUpdated";
```

Ofcourse this isnt working. Does anyone know how to do this?

Is it actually possible with `override` and is `override` suposed to be used like this? Or is it only for overriding functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can NOT change value of a constant. Why do you use it? it doesn't have to be constant to be static. Then you can change it's value easily from anywhere like this: Global.test = "new string";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't 'override' variables; simply change their value in the subclass (a constructor is a good place for this).

```
public function File1()
{
    test = "testStringUpdated";
}
```

As for literally overriding, you can override setters and getters.

Simply set up your variable as a setter/getter combination in the base class, eg:

```
class Base
{
    private var _test:String = "testString";

    public function get test():String
    {
        return _test;
    }

    public function set test(value:String):void
    {
        _test = value;
    }
}
```

Then in your subclass (File1), you can alter how the value of `test` will be obtained, eg:

```
class File1 extends Base
{
    override public function get test():String
    {
        return super.test + "Updated"; // testStringUpdated
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method worked perfect, i have a globalConfig class and a localConfig class, i simply extended from the globalConfig class and changed the values. I got one more question for you, since i let the localConfig extend from the globalConfig, why cant i adress the globalConfig through the localConfig? Say i have a variable test in my globalConfig, i cant use localConfig.test? Eventhough it extends from globalConfig?

Comment: @vincent You don't use `localConfig.test` in this case. Becase `localConfig` inherits from `globalConfig`, `test` belong to `localConfig` in the same way that it belongs to `globalConfig`. This means that you simply access that property via `test` from within both of those classes.